# Given the sequence Y as input, chooses a sequence X such the value of C is maximum

Tags: algorithm, math, sequence

Given two sequences of integers `X = (x1, x2, . . . , xn)` and `Y = (y1, y2, . . . , yn)` such that `1 ≤ xi ≤ yi` for all `1 ≤ i ≤ n`.

And let `C = Summation(from i=2 to n) |xi − xi-1|`

Given the sequence `Y` as input, I have to choose a sequence `X` that maximizes `C`.

---

Here's what I tried :

I can easily observe that for `Summation(i=2 to n) | xi - xi-1 |` to be maximum either `xi = yi` or `xi =  1` for all `i` in `n`.

But I do not know how to represent it mathematically.

Comment: Did you really mean `|xi − xi−1|` or did you mean `|yi − xi−1|`? The first is trivially and identically equal to `1`. Or did you mean ` |x(i) − x(i−1)|`?

Comment: I mean | x`1` -  x`i-1` | . And How is it trivially equal to 1 ?

Comment: What you just wrote differs from your question. Taken as computer code, your question says to take the value of variable `xi`, subtract the value of `xi`, subtract `1`, then take the absolute value of all that. Since you subtracted a value from itself, you are taking the absolute value of `-1`. If you mean the `i` and `i-1` to be *subscripts* or *indices* you need to put them in parentheses or brackets, depending on the computer language. Is that what you mean?

Comment: ohh .. sorry .. mistake .. i'll edit it now

Answer (score 0):

|Xi - Xi-1|  is maximized when `Xi=MAX(Yi)`  and `Xi-1=MIN(Yi)` or `Xi=MIN(Yi)` and `Xi-1=MAX(Yi)`.

So if `1 ≤ xi ≤ yi for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n. (A)`, would not hold, the X sequence would be:

```
X = MAX(yi), MIN(yi), MAX(yi), MIN(yi)....
```

or

```
X =  MIN(yi), MAX(yi), MIN(yi), MAX(Yi)....
```

Now, because we need to fulfill `(A)` the above sequence is transformed to:

```
MAX(yi) -> MAX(Yi) such that MAX(Yi)<=Yi <=> MAX(Yi)=Yi
MIN(Yi) -> MIN(Yi) such that MIN(Yi)<=Yi <=> MIN(Yi)=1
```

So, in conclusion, X sequence is:

```
X = 1, Y2, 1, Y4....
```

or

```
X = Y1, 1, Y3, 1 ...
```

Calculating the `Sum(|Xi-Xi-1|)`  for both the above, will give you the result.

**EDIT:**
As you correctly observe,  each Xi will either be Yi or 1. That means, for a given Y sequence of Length N, the Number of valid X sequences are 2^N. So an easy (brute force, not optimal for sure) algorithm would be to create all this sequences, compute corresponding sum, and take the one that Sum is maximum.

Comment: But what if I have a sequence Y = (11,5,4,8)  , then I get a maximum of 17  if i choose my X = (11 ,1 , 1 , 8 ) . which according to your solution I maximum of 13 with  X = (11,1,4,1) .

Comment: you are right, let me reconsider (in my case it is 16 not 13)

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly observed, for every `i` there are only 2 options: either `xi = 1` or `xi = yi`. That still leaves `2n` sequences to brute-force, though.

Luckily we can do better. We can just loop over the indices and keep track of two maximum sums:

- the maximum sum given that `xi = 1`, let's call that `maxLow`, and
- the maximum sum given that `xi = yi`, let's call that `maxHigh`

in the end we just need to take the maximum of those two.

---

Now we just need a way to update those two maximum sums but that's easy. There are 4 cases:

1. for `xi-1 = 1` and `xi = 1`: `maxLow = maxLow + |1 - 1|`
2. for `xi-1 = yi-1` and `xi = 1`: `maxLow = maxHigh + |1 - yi-1|`
3. for `xi-1 = 1` and `xi = yi`: `maxHigh = maxLow + |yi - 1|`
4. for `xi-1 = yi-1` and `xi = yi`: `maxHigh = maxHigh + |yi - yi-1|`

In code:

```
maxLow = 0
maxHigh = 0

for i = 2; i <= n; i++ {
    maxLow = max(maxLow, maxHigh + Y[i-1] - 1)
    maxHigh = max(maxLow + Y[i] - 1, maxHigh + abs(Y[i] - Y[i-1]))
}

result = max(maxLow, maxHigh)
```

This clearly runs in `O(n)` time.